# nVidia Quadro K620 over ExpressCard interface not working

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

I've got an nVidia Quadro K620 mounted on an ExpressCard adapter since a while, lieing about in a tech stuff box. So recently I got an HP Elitebook 8640p which has an ExpressCard interface, and builtin Intel graphics, to be able to use that GPU without having to build it into a laptop / PC.

So I installed the corresponding drivers (`sudo apt install nvidia-driver-535`) and rebooted.
Then I plugged in the express card plug of the nVidia card. After that, the Quadro appeared as `VGA compatible controller` in the output of `lspci`, but - `nvidia-smi` said that it couldn't find any compatible devices !

Most probably the GPU needs to be plugged in at boot time (?), I thought, so I left it plugged in and rebooted. Which got me - a black screen. Instead of the GRUB boot selector and login screen appearing, the screen stayed black. If I unplugged the NVidia card, everything worked normally again, but I couldn't use the GPU then, obviously.

So:

1. Are there any other physical connections needed between the express card adapter and the laptop, other than the express card interface plug itself ?
2. If that's not the case / problem, then what else could be the problem ? Anything I could do to get this to work ?

I'm running Ubuntu Studio 22.04.

Comment: Check egpu.io/forums for info on external gpus.  I ran x gtx 970 in a expresscard/pci adapter without problems, but I did have additional external power supplied to the card. Did you install the Nvidia drivers for the 6.5 kernel?  Might need to try again (recent fix on getting gcc-12 for the module build).

Comment: Yeah, I've got an extra AC power supply hooked up to it too (old PC power supply I think). So, for you, the only connection between the PC and the PCI adapter was the express card cable @ubfan1 ?

Comment: Correct, only the expresscard cable.  Do look for a build like yours at egpu.io, they have a large number of searchable examples. I left my cable in all the time, and it booted normally, but I did have to turn off the machine's internal GPU first. Ubuntu never had a problem with the setup, but Windows eventually took over some Nvidia functions and messed things up (device manager could see the 970, but the display settings could not).